# Python, compute array difference in exact amount of elements

Tags: python, arrays, diff

I have two lists in Python, like these:

```
temp1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C','C']
temp2 = ['A','B','C','C']
```

I need to create a third list with items from the first list which will be different with exact number of elements existing in temp2, I need to create below :

```
temp3 = ['A','A','C']
```

What is the best way of doing that ? Using sets is not working as expected, so that would like to now is there a fast way to do it with python standart functions or i have to create my own function ?

Comment: Do you know that list1 is a superset of list2?

Comment: Yep, that's definite.

Comment: `for i in temp2: temp1.remove(i)`…?

Comment: Using sets gets rid of duplicates. Also is the order guaranteed? You can do better then remove if so.

Comment: In fact you can do better regardless I now realize.

Comment: thanks, marked as similiar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

temp1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
temp2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C']

result = []

counts = Counter(temp2)

for item in temp1:
    if item in counts and counts[item]:
        counts[item] -= 1
    else:
        result.append(item)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'A', 'C']
```

Scales O(n) and does not rely on sorted input.

This answer relies on the fact that `Counter` is just a subclass of `dict`, so we can use the instance as a mutable object in which to store the number of occurrences in `temp2` that we still need to exclude from the result during the iteration over `temp1`.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) states explicitly that "`Counter` is a `dict` subclass" and that "`Counter` objects have a dictionary interface", which is a pretty good guarantee that item assignment will be supported, and that it is not necessary to treat it as a read-only object that must first be copied into a plain `dict`.

Answer (score 4):

```
temp1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C','C']
temp2 = ['A','B','C','C']
# create a copy of your first list
temp3 = list(temp1)
# remove every item from the second list of the copy
for e in temp2:
    temp3.remove(e)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'A', 'C']
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but this is brute-force solution and routes me to way that i need to create my own method, what i was asking is to use one of "standart" python functions or not, in  any case thanks for your kind reccomendation.

Comment: I don't think, that there is a builtin function which does the work for you.

Comment: For long lists this will be very time consuming.

Answer (score 4):

If the lists are guaranteed to be sorted you can do much better in terms of time complexity than `list.remove` or counting every iteration using:

```
temp1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
temp2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C']

filtered = []
j = 0
for i, letter in enumerate(temp1):
    while j < len(temp2) and temp2[j] < letter:
        j += 1
    if j == len(temp2):
        break

    if temp2[j] > letter:
        filtered.append(letter)
    else:
        j += 1

filtered.extend(temp1[i:])
```

**Another solution**

A more interesting solution I thought of:

```
from collections import Counter
result = []
for letter, count in (Counter(temp1)-Counter(temp2)).items():
    result.extend([letter]*count)
```

This is the same big O complexity as the above.

**If lists are not sorted**

If order is not important these solutions are still much faster, since sorting the lists is cheaper than the O(n^2) solutions, and the second one doesn't even need that.  If it is, this still works, you just need to retain a mapping of element->index (which your `temp1` already is) before sorting, though this might be out of scope for this question.

Comment: Definitely worth using a counter, because this is O(n) -- assuming dictionary access is O(1). There's a straightforward O(n) solution based on counter, which preserves the ordering in list1, which I've added as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
temp1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C','C']
temp2 = ['A','B','C','C']
temp3 = []

for i in temp1:
    if temp1.count(i) - temp2.count(i) > temp3.count(i):
        temp3.append(i)
print(temp3)
```

This code will check if in temp3 all the diff elements init and if not it will append the relevant temp1 item to the temp3 list.

Output

```
['A', 'A', 'C']
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, though even less efficient then the `remove` solution. Gave me an idea though.